# Python Beautifulsoup htmltableextraction issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-tableextract

I'm trying to extract data from html table which is bit unstructured.
HTML Table structure as below (sample data) -

[image: HTML Table structure as below (sample data)]

Able to extract data but facing issue with the "ID" column. "ID" is the single header for 2 columns, that too structure is not consistent through out the table.

Running the Below Code -

```
#Libraries 
import urllib3, re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

group_techniques = []
#Loop through the URLs we loaded above
for b in base_url:
    html = requests.get(b).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    
#provide the table name we want to scrape
    group_table = soup.find('table', {"class" : "table techniques-used table-bordered mt-2"})

#try clause to skip any url with missing/empty tables
    try:
#loop through table, grab each of the 5 columns shown
        for row in group_table.find_all('tr'):
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            if len(cols) == 5:
                group_techniques.append((b, cols[0].text.strip(), cols[1].text.strip(), cols[2].text.strip(),
                                         cols[3].text.strip(),cols[4].text.strip()))
    except: pass
```

```
#convert output to new array
group_tech_array = np.asarray(group_techniques)

#convert array to dataframe
df_grp_tech = pd.DataFrame(group_tech_array)

#rename columns, check output
df_grp_tech.columns = ['Domain','Tech_ID','sub_id','Name','Use']
```

When we compare Actual Output vs Expected output -

- We are missing row #3 (T1560) from the raw html table
- We are missing row #5 (T1059) from the raw html table
  It is because of complex table structure

**Actual Table structure after extraction**

[image]

**Expected Table structure**

[image]

** HTML Table **  [Here is the link "Table - Techniques Used"](https://attack.mitre.org/groups/G0004/)

Comment: Can you provide your table structures as text, please? For better readability

Comment: yes sir - this would be great. if you provide this data then we would be able to help you.

Comment: here is the link, https://attack.mitre.org/groups/G0004/  
table to be used is "Techniques Used"

Comment: And trim it down too. 5 rows w sample weird structure is better than throwing 20 rows in and letting us sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler, in this case at least, to use pandas:

```
tables = pd.read_html('https://attack.mitre.org/groups/G0004/')
tables[1]
```

And that's it. The output is your target table.

Comment: I added a line to forwardfill NaN values  `tables = pd.read_html('https://attack.mitre.org/groups/G0004/')
tech_table = tables[1]

tech_table.fillna(method='ffill') `